# Sparse Matrix by Using Multiple Linked-lists

Tags: c, linked-list, sparse-matrix

I want to sum all the row and column values of the sparse matrix and show them as an output by using multiple linked-lists. By doing this I am told to use the `struct` as shown below and also the `struct` arrays. Can you please help me how to design the code? I am struggling to code multiple linked-lists also the how to record the row and the columns values by using:

```
struct Node {
    int row;
    int col;
    int value;
    struct Node *next_right;
    struct Node *next_down;
};
    
struct Node *ArrayOfRows[NR] = {NULL};
struct Node *ArrayOfCols[NC] = {NULL};
```

To understand the linked list structure I code as if the problem only have one pointer which is the `struct Node *next_right` but for multiple linked-lists I am troubling to code that.

Comment: Do you have to use the struct you have? It would be easier to use three structs (e.g.) matrix, list, and node. It seems you said yes but is that a _hard_ requirement?

Comment: Also, using the arrays limits the sparseness

Comment: Please _edit_ your question and post the code that you have that creates and manipulates the matrix and nodes

Comment: it is told that multiple linked-list is used with the struct. I guess using matrix is would help to find the total row and total column.

Comment: As i said the aim is to find the sum of each row and column by using the code above which is struct and the arrays(ArrayOfRows and ArrayOfCols)